# Why do I have this infinite loop

Tags: c++

hey guys kind of new to the programming world and I know you should read in all input as a string but this is just a simple program and I'm having a brain fart I think but here is my question......why when I press q to quit am i getting an infinite loop and how would I condense the while loops because that looks gross
here is what I have so far

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int grade;
    char quit = 'a';

    cout << "Input your grade (0-100): ";
    cout << endl;
    cin >> grade;
    while (grade < 0) {
        cout << "If you have a negetive grade....drop out! otherwise enter another grade" << endl;
        cin >> grade;
    }
    while (quit != 'q') {
        while (grade < 0) {
            cout << "If you have a negetive grade....drop out! otherwise enter another grade" << endl;
            cin >> grade;
        }

        if (grade == 100) {
            cout << "You got a perfect grade!" << endl;
            cout << "Letter grade: A" << endl;
        }
        else if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100) {
            cout << "Letter grade: A" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89) {
            cout << "Letter grade: B" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79) {
            cout << "Letter grade: C" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69) {
            cout << "Letter grade: D" << endl << endl;
        }
        else if (grade < 60) {
            cout << "Letter grade: F" << endl << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid grade!" << endl;
        }
        cout << " would you like to enter another grade? or press q to quit" << endl;
        cin >> grade;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: You never seem to actually change the variable `quit`.

Comment: you test wether `quit` is unequal to the letter 'q', however you set the variable to 'a' explicitly at the top and never update it. I suggest you change your second `while` condition to `while (quit != grade)` and initialize `quit` to 'q' . It is far from the most beautiful approach but it should work!

Answer (score 2):

Because of `grade` var. You declared `grade` as `int`.
If you type correct `int`, it works well, but If you type another `char` ex:) `q` or `f`, function `cin` cannot recognize `q` or `f` as `int` type.

If `char` input, `cin` pass own process.

You have to change `grade` type into `char` to recognize `char` and `int` inputs both.

If you want to use only one input flow, this implementation code will help you.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char c_input[32] = {0};
    cin>>c_input;

    while(atoi(c_input) < 0)
    {
        cout<<"If you have a negative grade....drop out! otherwise enter another grade" << endl;
        cin>>c_input;
    }
    while(c_input[0] != 'q')
    {
        while(atoi(c_input) < 0)
        {
            cout<<"If you have a negative grade....drop out! otherwise enter another grade" << endl;
            cin>>c_input;
        }
        cout<<c_input;
        cout<<"Would you like to enter another grade? or press q to quit" << endl;
        cin>>c_input;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimal, verifiable example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int grade;
    char quit = 'a';

    cout << "Input your grade (0-100): ";
    cout << endl;
    cin >> grade;
    while (quit != 'q') {
        cout << " would you like to enter another grade? or press q to quit" << endl;
        cin >> grade;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;`enter code here`
}
```

See the problem with `quit`?

**edit**
What I have done is remove (most of) the lines that have nothing to do with `quit` or the loop.

At this point you should notice that the loop *never changes quit*.

If you are having trouble with a program, one of the best ways to figure out what is wrong is to get rid of everything that doesn't have anything to do with the error. In time, you'll be able to do this *using only your mind.* Duuude!

**while i'm at it**
The correct way to handle user input is to get it as a *string*, then convert it to what you want.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
T string_to( const std::string& s )
{
  T value;
  std::istringstream ss( s );
  ss >> value >> std::ws;
  if (!ss.eof()) throw std::invalid_argument("T string_to()");
  return value;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Enter a number or 'q': ";
  std::string s;
  getline( std::cin, s );

  if (s == 'q')
  {
    std::cout << "Good job! You entered 'q'.\n";
  }
  else
  {
    try
    {
      double x = string_to <double> ( s );
      std::cout << "Good job! You entered '" << x << "'.\n";
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
      std::cout << "Foo, you didn't obey instructions and made me " << e.what() << ".\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although the condensed version does help, I feel you should probably just explain what the issue is anyway. At a glance this doesn't look like much of an answer, but if you showed the OP how you cut down their issue into a smaller problem to aid solving, then show what the issue is, it would go a long way.

Comment: Well put. Fixed.